# If the product of $n$ positive definite matrices is symmetric, is it also positive definite?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, symmetric-matrices, positive-definite, positive-semidefinite

A well-known result for the product of two PD (or PSD) matrices is:

> **Proposition:** Let $A$ and $B$ be positive definite (respectively positive semidefinite) Hermitian matrices of the same size. If $D:=AB$ is Hermitian, then $D$ is also positive definite (respectively positive semidefinite).

This can be extended to the product of three PD (or PSD) matrices: [Is the product of three positive semidefinite matrices positive semidefinite](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/654587/is-the-product-of-three-positive-semidefinite-matrices-positive-semidefinite)

> **Proposition:** Let $A$, $B$, and  $C$ be positive definite (respectively positive semidefinite) Hermitian matrices of the same size. If $D:=ABC$ is Hermitian, then $D$ is also positive definite (respectively positive semidefinite).

Is there any extension of this to the product of $n$ PD (or PSD) matrices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Here is a random counterexample. Let
$$
P=\pmatrix{3&6&8\\ 8&8&4\\ 2&4&5},
\quad\Lambda=\pmatrix{4\\ &8\\ &&12},
\quad D=\pmatrix{1\\ &-1\\ &&-1}
$$
and
$$
A=P\Lambda P^{-1}
=\pmatrix{36&-3&-36\\ -64&0&112\\ 16&-2&-12}.
$$
One may use a computer to verify that $AD$ has three different positive eigenvalues $4$ and $2(11\pm\sqrt{97})$. Since every diagonalisable real square matrix with a positive spectrum is a product of two positive definite matrices, we have $A^{-1}=S_1S_2$ and $AD=S_3S_4$ for some $S_1,S_2,S_3,S_4\succ0$. Now $S_1S_2S_3S_4=D$, which is indefinite.